# Unexpected perplexing error thrown

Tags: java, string, list, exception

I'm writing a rather simple Java program that prompts the user for 2 Strings, following which the first string is formatted according to the second one and outputted accordingly.

This processing proceeds by deleting every character in the first string that corresponds with each character in the second string and outputting the first string after the intended changes. This might be looking baffling and incomprehensible.

For example:
suppose we've got the following 2 strings as input:

```
lennon
Ln
```

Output:

```
eo
```

After removing every occurrence of the characters 'L' & 'n' from the first String (without regard to case)

This is the pertinent program :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.format("Enter 2 Strings, schmuck:%n");
String s1 = br.readLine();
String s2 = br.readLine();
List<Character> l = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
{
    l.add(s1.charAt(i));
}
char ch;
for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++)
{
    ch=s2.charAt(i);

    while((l.indexOf(ch)) != -1)
    {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(ch))
        l.remove(ch);
        l.remove(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
    }
}
for(Character c : l)
{
    System.out.printf("%c", c);
}
```

It's throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I find it eerie and perplexing and feel I've reached an impasse. Maybe it's a silly error. Any sort of help would be ecstatically appreciated.

Comment: Thats a job for regex replace and not nested for / while loops

Comment: Your program will not quite do what you expect it to, by the way. Try the following strings: `lennon` and `LN`, then figure out why.

Comment: Gee...kind of missed out on making the pertinent case congruous prior to entering the while loop, eh. Ta, mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
       l.remove(Character.valueOf(ch));
       l.remove(Character.valueOf(Character.toLowerCase(ch)));
```

My guess is that `List.remove(int)` is used in your code, where the int is an index in the list.

The stacktrace will give the correct line number where the exception happens. Always check that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try by converting 2 string either to upper or lower case and then get the index of the each char in second string and if it is not equal to -1 then remove it

```
        String s1 = "lennon";
        String s2 = "Ln";

        s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
        s2 = s2.toLowerCase();
        List<Character> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            l.add(s1.charAt(i));
        }
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
            ch = s2.charAt(i);

            while ((l.indexOf(ch)) != -1) {
                l.remove(l.indexOf(ch));
            }
        }
        for (Character c : l) {
            System.out.printf("%c", c);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of more changes needed for you program to work. Anyways, try the below code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.format("Enter 2 Strings, schmuck:%n");
        String s1=br.readLine();
        String s2=br.readLine();
        List<Character> l = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
        {
            l.add(s1.charAt(i));
        }
        char ch;
       for(int i=0;i<s2.length();i++)
       {
           ch=s2.charAt(i);

           while((l.indexOf(ch))!=-1 || (l.indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(ch)))!=-1)
           {
               if(Character.isUpperCase(ch))
              l.remove(new Character(Character.toLowerCase(ch)));
               l.remove(new Character(ch));
           }
       }
       for(Character c : l)
           {
           System.out.printf("%c", c);
           }
    }
```